# FileUpload not saving in Project directory

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using Ajaxtoolkit fileupload but uploaded files are not saving in specified directory.
Fileuploader is works fine but saves no file in directory, SO I checked my browser console and it says **"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cannotDeserializeEmptyString' of undefined"** I want to know what it means I searched but could not find.

Here is the code behind.

```
protected void AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(e.FileName);
        string dir = "~/Uploads/";
        AjaxFileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(dir + fileName));
    }
```

Comment: Make sure you have already created a folder named as `Uploads` in your Project root directory.

Comment: I have folder name Uploads in my project.

Comment: Use  `AjaxFileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(Path.Combine(dir, fileName)));`

Comment: @mmushtaq I have tried all avilable methods that .Net has for upload controller, The problem was in webconfig file. I had to handle it.